# Shortcuts editor doesn't recognize boolean EntityQueryProperty

Tags: ios, swift, sirishortcuts

My `AppEntity` has a `Bool` property, and I would like to query by this property using the new `EntityPropertyQuery` from AppIntents. I'm creating an `EntityQueryProperty` for it with an `EqualToComparator` as the following (partial code for brevity):

```
// My AppEntity
struct AlbumAppEntity: AppEntity, Identifiable {
    @Property(title: "Hidden")
    var isHidden: Bool

    // Other properties
}

// My EntityPropertyQuery
static var properties = QueryProperties {
    Property(\AlbumAppEntity.$isHidden) {
        EqualToComparator { isHidden in
            if isHidden {
                return NSPredicate(format: "isHidden == YES")
            } else {
                return NSCompoundPredicate(type: .or, subpredicates: [NSPredicate(format: "isHidden = nil"), NSPredicate(format: "isHidden == NO")])
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But the problem is that Shortcuts does not recognize it as a boolean parameter in the shortcuts editor. It recognizes it as a numeric field, which returns the error AppIntents.EntityPropertyQueryError error 2 when run:

[image]

I also tried different `NSPredicate`, but the result is always the same:

```
Property(\AlbumAppEntity.$isHidden) {
    EqualToComparator { NSPredicate(format: "isHidden == %d", $0) }
}

Property(\AlbumAppEntity.$isHidden) {
    EqualToComparator { NSPredicate(format: "isHidden == %@", NSNumber(value: $0)) }
}
```

How can I query using boolean properties in a way that Shortcuts recognizes it and provides appropriate field in the shortcuts editor?